# How to call abstract method from abstract class called by inherit class

Tags: java, inheritance

I want to call a method of an abstract class from abstract class called by inherit class.

Abstract class:

```
public abstract class Abstract {
    protected void updateMotionY(float deltaTime) {
        System.out.println("Abstrcat updateMotionY");
    }
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        this.updateMotionY(deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Inherit class:

```
public class Obj extends Abstract {
    @Override
    protected void updateMotionY(float deltaTime) {
        System.out.println("updateMotionY");
        super.updateMotionY(deltaTime);
    }
    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        super.update(deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Main method class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    (new Obj()).update(10.0f);
}
```

Whenever I try to call `new Obj().update()` method in main class, it prints "updateMotionY" and "Abstrcat updateMotionY". I want to get only "Abstrcat updateMotionY".

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: *"it throws: updateMotionY and Abstrcat updateMotionY"* No, it doesn't, that isn't what exceptions (things you "throw") look like. Do you mean it *outputs* that? And if so, why does that surprise you? You're telling it to.

Comment: The override of `update()` in the `Obj` class is redundant.

Comment: It shows in console updateMotionY and Abstrcat updateMotionY. Both methods are called. I want to call only abstract method.

Comment: Use proper terms: "throws" refers to exceptions or errors. You mean "prints" or "displays".

Comment: thanks for the advaise I corrected thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(new Obj()).update(10.0f)` calls `Obj::update` which calls `Abstract::update` which calls `this.updateMotionY`. Because `this` is an instance of `Obj`, this calls `Obj::updateMotionY`.

This prints "updateMotionY".

This then calls `super.updateMotionY(deltaTime)` which is `Abstract::updateMotionY`.

This prints "Abstrcat updateMotionY".

That's the end of the call hierarchy and everything unwinds.

---

Fundamentally your confusion seems to stem from the fact that `this.updateMotionY(deltaTime);` in the `Abstract` class resolves to `updateMotionY` in the `Obj` class. That's basically [the whole point of polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function).

---

One thing you could do is to add a private method (so that it cant be overridden) which contains the actual implementation, and defer to it:

```
public abstract class Abstract {
    private void motionY(float dt)
    {
        System.out.println("Abstrcat updateMotionY");
    }

    protected void updateMotionY(float deltaTime) {
        motionY(deltaTime);
    }
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        motionY(deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: but how to call Abstract::update excluding the Obj::update, when I remove this clause  it would change nothing

Comment: Edited my answer with one possible way of doing that.

Comment: Nice explanations. Where I have some other ideas in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are using `abstract` in a very wrong way. Your **base** class should rather look like this:

```
public abstract class Abstract {
  protected abstract void updateMotionY(float deltaTime);

  public final void update(float deltaTime) {
    this.updateMotionY(deltaTime);
  }
}
```

Notes:

- there is no point putting print "is abstract" into an abstract method. The java language has a keyword to express this fact.
- subclasses should **only** be about **implementing** the abstract method(s) (probably in different ways). You absolutely do **not** want that subclasses change the *implementation* of other methods of the base class. Your base class defines a *contract* - and subclasses should adhere to that (as outlined by the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle)).

In other words: put the *common* parts solely in the base class, and make sure that you have to necessary `abstract` methods in there to do that. But *avoid* implementing methods more than once. That only leads to confusion and strange bugs.

Comment: Yep. I think this is the structure he should be using.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to execute the abstracts superclass' method, then the simple solution is to just call `super.updateMotionY` instead of `super.update` in your Obj class

```
public class Obj extends Abstract {
    @Override
    protected void updateMotionY(float deltaTime) {
        System.out.println("updateMotionY: ");
        super.updateMotionY(deltaTime);
    }
    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        super.updateMotionY(deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of Abstract class so you're creating an instance of Obj class. Since your requirement is only to call method of Abstract class then why did you override the method **updateMotionY**

For your requirement this is what you need to do
Abstract class:

```
public abstract class Abstract {
    protected void updateMotionY(float deltaTime) {
        System.out.println("Abstrcat updateMotionY");
    }
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        this.updateMotionY(deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Inherit class:

```
public class Obj extends Abstract{
    /*@Override
    protected void updateMotionY(float deltaTime) {
        System.out.println("updateMotionY");
        super.updateMotionY(deltaTime);
    }*/
    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        super.update(deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I have commented the overridden code which will give you the required result.
Also, the answer given by https://stackoverflow.com/users/8466177/steven-laan will also work.